# Difference in RIA services between .NET 3.5 and 4?

Tags: .net-3.5, .net-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am about to start a new project.  Using VS2010, Silverlight 4, and RIA Services are a given.  However, due to the web server we have available, there is some question of whether we can use .NET 4 or whether we will have to stick to .NET 3.5.  I know that RIA Services can work with .NET 3.5.  But what I'm curious about is whether there is any difference in functionality with RIA services between 3.5 and 4.  Would I be missing any big features?  If so, I might push harder on the server team to get .NET 4 installed in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you can use .NET 3.5 on the server with RIA Services ?

The DLLs I have in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Server\ all have a target runtime of v4.0.30319.

Comment: Y'know, I've been trying to prove that to myself since I wrote this question.  I know that the betas of RIA Services were available for VS 2008 / .NET 3.5.  But I see the same thing you do.  Still investigating...

Comment: Indeed the download page does not have anything but the VS 2010 install from what I can find.  I guess that answers my question then. :-)

Comment: I agree, I had run the beta with .NET 3.5. And I could not find a page that states the .NET version dependency.

Comment: WCF RIA Services V1.0 only runs on .NET 4.0. The Beta for 3.5 is available and 'go live', but it is not officially supported. If you have a choice, I'd recommend upgrading to .NET 4.